# How can I reset my HP 2000 Wifi card?

Tags: wireless-networking

When I boot my laptop, the wireless shows its turned off by a hardware switch, but toggling it doesn't work. On my linux partition (and the liveCD) it shows as being soft locked and it can't be unlocked.

It is a Ralink RT5390.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a hard reset. To do that, follow these directions:

First, disconnect **all** peripheral devices, remove all USB devices and media cards, including mice, external keyboards etc etc etc.

Now, disconnect the **AC power adapter**, remove the battery, and then press and hold the power button for **at least** 1 minute. I Held mine for two, just to make sure.

Now, reconnect your AC power adapter (do **not** connect the battery!!), press the Power button and check is this problem solved or not.

If not, then you might have a dead wifi adapter.

(as was posted [originally on the HP forums](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Wireless-Internet-Home/Pavilion-dv2000-problem-wireless-network-adapter-disappeared/m-p/726737#M16274))